# Why is the author of the novel "West of the Water Tower" not named?

Tags: homer-croy, west-of-the-water-tower, anonymity

I have a copy of the 1923 novel [*West of the Water Tower*](https://archive.org/details/westofwatertower00croy/page/n9/mode/2up) by Homer Croy.

Nowhere in the book is the author named, nor is there an "about the author" section. The last couple of pages advertise books by other authors.

Why did Mr. Croy and/or the publisher (Harper's) want to conceal the authorship of the work?

Comment: According to [this page](https://norman.hrc.utexas.edu/bookshopdoor/signature.cfm?item=171#1) from the University of Texas at Austin: "*Croy's novel, a drama set in the fictional town of Junction City, was a thinly veiled critique of his own hometown, Marysville, Missouri. He published it anonymously because its serious tone so conflicted with his well-known light-hearted writings about midwestern life.*" (I was going to post this as an answer, but Gareth got there first with a much better answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Eugene Jolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_Jolas) says that Harper’s were concerned that the serious novel did not fit Croy’s established brand as a humorous writer of “lighter yarns”:

> It will be remembered that [Croy] was the subject of a great literary mystery when Harper’s published his *West of the Water Tower*. Rescued out of a prize competition, it was published anonymously, and the secret was kept for almost three months. “Because I had previously confined my literary activities  to writing humorous and lighter yarns, Harper’s, when they decided to publish , did not want to bill me as a ‘serious thinker,’” he said to us whimsically. […] “Percy Hammond of the *New York Herald Tribune* got hold of the fact one day, while we were having a party at the home of Burns Mantle, dramatic critic of the *Daily News* and *Chicago Tribune*. Somebody evidently put him wise, and when he asked me some questions about it point-blank, I did not realize that he was not aware of it. I gave it away. Then he wrote a long, laudatory article revealing my name. The next morning Harper’s called me up, and there was a great deal of excitement. I had to dictate a flat-footed denial of the authorship, but it was considered too strong, and I finally decided on a humorous, evasive answer. The reply was published, but it was too late. I had become a ‘serious thinker.’”
>
> <sub>Eugene Jolas (1924). [*Rambles Through Literary Paris*, number 36](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0ek9VP-2n-MC&pg=PA53). In Klaus H. Kiefer and Rainer Rumold, eds. (2009). *Eugene Jolas: Critical Writings 1924–1951*, p. 53. Northwestern University Press.</sub>

David Anderson says that Croy was concerned about criticism due to his choice to write in the old-fashioned “home-town” genre:

> *West of the Water Tower* [… is] rooted in the tradition defined by [Carl Van Doren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Van_Doren) in his 1921 essay “[The Revolt from the Village](https://archive.org/details/contemporaryame00vand/page/146/mode/2up),” and Croy, aware of home-town criticism received by [Sherwood] Anderson and others, published *West of the Water Tower* anonymously in 1923.
>
> <sub>David D. Anderson (2001). ‘[Homer Croy](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZnuYKJSoHCMC&pg=PA125)’. In Philip A. Greasley, ed. (2001). *Dictionary of Midwestern Literature*, volume 1, p. 125. Indiana University Press.</sub>

Of these two accounts I find that of Jolas the more plausible, being closer in time to the events and based on the testimony of the author. But the accounts are not incompatible: Harper’s could have been concerned both about the work being off-brand and out-of-date. Some impression of how the “home-town” genre was perceived at the time can be found in the opening to a contemporary review of Croy’s novel:

> The older novels of “local color” that spread pandering quaintness before complacency and drew out unctuous gobs of fat laughter from leering superiority, and the more pretentious tales of the simple life that preyed upon the factitious tear from the more or less practicable eye have given place to satires and tragedies of small towns and farms.
>
> <sub>John W. Crawford (1923). ‘[Cotton and Corn](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.c041399039&view=1up&seq=696)’. In *The Nation* 116:3022 (6th June 1923), p. 668.</sub>